# How to make a for loop in this case?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do pagination on the angular. I found a working solution in Google, but I can’t correctly implement it.

*app.component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

orders: Orders;

config: any;
collection = { count: 100, data: [] };

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

// Create dummy data
for (let i = 0; i < this.collection.count; i++) {
  this.collection.data.push(
    {
      id: i + 1,
      value: 'items number ' + (i + 1)
    }
  );
}

this.config = {
  itemsPerPage: 5,
  currentPage: 1,
  totalItems: this.collection.count
};
}

ngOnInit(){
this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders').subscribe((data: Orders) => this.orders = data);
}

pageChanged(event){
this.config.currentPage = event;
}

}
```

*app.component.html*

```
      <table class="table">
    <tbody>

    <p *ngFor="let order of orders">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of collection.data | paginate: config">
    <th scope="row">{{item.id}}</th>
    <td>  {{order?.customer}}</td>
    </tr>
    </p>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"></pagination-controls>
```

*Result*

[image: result]

But need:

1 Hilary Greer

2 yen Ortega

3 Maris Okonnor

4 Sybill Gregory

5 Briar Lee

How to fix it?

Comment: can you add the JSON returned from your backend please.

Comment: @NTP [
{
"id": 1000,
"customer": "Hilary Greer",
}, {
"id": 1001,
"customer": "yen Ortega",
}, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your HTML To :-

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="let order of orders | paginate: config ; let i=index">
    <th scope="row">{{index+1}}</th>
    <td>  {{order?.customer}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"></pagination-controls>
```